# Как форматировать данные перед записью в state react js

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

При помощи axios.get приходят данные в массив в стейте, структура массива выглядит так:

```
info: [
{
_id:23194913094,
data: {name: Alex , age: 21, id:23194913094}
},
{
такие же по структуре объекты
},....]
```

но не в каждом объекте data заполнен id. вопрос: как вместо пустого id, вставить _id который на уровень выше и записать в стейт уже в таком виде?

Comment: _id автоматически генерируется, id должен быть такой же как и _id

Answer (score 0):

```js
axios.get(url)
  .then(({data}) => {
     this.setState({
      info: data.map(item => ({...item, id: item.id ? item.id : item._id})
     })
  })
```